# Acrotex and Eqexam

Tags: mactex

I am a MacTeX 2013 user and I have installed `acrotex` first and then `eqexam` by following the directions outlined by Alan Munn found at this link:

[Eforms on Mac OS X](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29723/eforms-on-mac-os-x)

I proceeded to test the installation by attempting to compile `fortextbook.ltx` found in the doc folder in the `eqexam` zip folder. I then changed line 3 to `\def\mydriver{pdftex}`; I commented out lines 6, 23, and line 19 (because I don’t have the lucida fonts) but I uncomment lines 4, 5, and 7,9-12, and I receive a bunch of errors for example:

```
LaTeX Error: Command \eqemargin already defined. .. l.251 \newlength{\eqemargin}
LaTeX Error: Command \prbPrtsep already defined.
```

I have even tried compiling a smaller file such as the one found at this link:

[clickable problem book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111903/clickable-problem-book)

but I get similar error. Can someone please advise what I can do to make sure my installation correct or tell how to fix the files I am trying to compile so that they compile error free?

I am not concerned with the missing psgraphs errors but only the errors that involve acrotex and eqexam.